# Why there ist no getChars(int i, int index, char[] buf) method in the official Java Documentation of Integer.class

Tags: java, integer, documentation

When I look for the Integer.class file in Eclipse, i can find the getChars Method: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHXIf.jpg

But in the official Java Documentation there is no getChars Method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Why?

Comment: Because it's not public, so it's not listed. In fact it is a internal method invoked when you call `Integer.toString()`, you can't call it directly.

Comment: Is there a way to look up the not public-methods in the documentation?

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: because i want to have a quick overview of all methods of a class

Comment: The only one you can use are the public ones. (excepted if you extends those classes but I don't see why anyone would extends classes like Integer) Stick to the javadoc

Comment: run this command in command prompt: `javap java.lang.Integer`

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: There is no point in *knowing* about internal methods. They are internal, you are not supposed to use / rely / whatever ... them. Next release, they might be gone. Or do something else.

Answer (score 5):

Because it's not `public`. It is only used internally.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the access modifier of `getChars` method, it is `default`. Hence we cannot use this method on an instance of Integer.

To list down all the method of a class, you can run `javap` command:

```
javap java.lang.Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of javadoc is to document the **public** API of a class (in the first place).

You only create javadoc for methods that *other* classes should be using. The method you are asking about is *package protected*. We are talking about the `java.lang` package. You can't add classes to that package, so for all practical purpose, you can regard this method to be **private**.

Coming from there: you simply shouldn't care about such methods. Studying their content might be nice for educational purposes, but they really do not matter for practical purposes. As they represent *implementation details*. They are subject to change, and you shouldn't rely on them to exist, or even to do a certain thing.